# Using Gulp with Sails Js

Tags: reactjs, gulp, sails.js

Hi I want to use Gulp with sailsJs can any one help me with the gulp hook.(I don't want to use grunt).Iam building an application with React+flux+React-Router(front end) and sailsJs as backend. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Sails.js website](http://sailsjs.org/features#?asset-pipeline) recommends using Paul Avery's [sails-generate-gulp-bower](https://github.com/PaulAvery/sails-generate-gulp-bower) generator which provides support for gulp and bower.